# Numpy: create random strings and make uniform

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
let = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(np.random.choice(let, 8, p=[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]))
```

output:

```
['A' 'B' 'C' 'A' 'A' 'C' 'A' 'A']
```

It should be random but I want the following output: 25% A, 25%, B, 25% C, 25% D. 
Something like the following:

```
['A' 'B' 'C' 'A' 'C' 'D' 'D' 'B']
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So, the number of elements in output would be double of input?

Comment: The number of elements of output could by any length. I just choose 8 as an example. But the actually number could be any. For instance, 100 A's, 100 B's, 100 C's, 100 D's would also work. I just want each element to be 25% of total

Comment: You want random *permutations* of eight A's, eight B's, eight C's and eight D's. Correct?

Comment: And the weights would always be uniformly distributed?

Comment: With permutations: `np.random.permutation(let*4)`

Comment: If I have 100 total letters composed of all As,Bs,Cs,Ds. I want these in any random order. But they should be composed of 25 As, 25Bs, 25Cs, 25Ds. In other words, each letter should be 25% of total

Comment: Sorry, meant to say 25 of each of the first four letters of the alphabet!

Comment: You want a random *multiset* (or bag) permutation. The total number of such permutations will be less than 100! but still huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per `RedEyed` comment:

```
import numpy as np
let = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(np.random.permutation(let*4))
```